# How are oxygen and nitrogen replenished in the storage tanks on the ISS?

Tags: iss, oxygen, tanks, eclss

How they add gases to high pressure tanks. Will the supply trucks bring it? And how will it be connected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original ISS design called for [High Pressure Gas Tanks](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17677/6944) (HPGTs) to be delivered by the shuttle. With the cessation of shuttle flights, a system called Nitrogen Oxygen Resupply System (NORS) was installed.

> High pressure resupply tanks called Recharge Tank Assemblies (RTAs) are now available to launch on visiting
> vehicles. These tanks are provided by the Nitrogen Oxygen Resupply System (NORS). The NORS consists of the
> RTAs, along with the Airlock Installation Kit (AIK) and Internal Fill Kit (IFK) support hardware to integrate the tanks
> into the existing nitrogen and oxygen plumbing in the Airlock. NORS can either support the oxygen and nitrogen
> systems directly or provide an equalization transfer to the external O2 HPGTs. The NORS RTAs are 48,263 kPa (7000
> psia) oxygen and nitrogen tanks with a volume of 0.076 m3 (2.68 ft3). The oxygen RTAs are filled with 38.1 kg (84
> lbm) O2 and the nitrogen RTAs are filled with 28.6 kg (63 lbm) N2.

[image]

Source [Report on ISS O2 Production, Gas Supply & Partial
Pressure Management](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20150010425/downloads/20150010425.pdf)

The linked paper is very informative about the logistics of gas supply to the ISS. Also of possible interest:

[Current Status of the Nitrogen Oxygen Recharge System](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110012004/downloads/20110012004.pdf)

Also, info about actual NORS ops since the first paper was written in 2015: https://www.nasa.gov/content/air-supply-high-pressure-tanks-ready-for-space-station

Comment: So is the entire tank always replaced?

Comment: It says that they can either use the tank as-is or refill the HPGT from it. If you look at page 6 in the paper, it sounds like they do a mix of both "It is
assumed that N2 NORS tanks will stay connected in the AIK and provide nitrogen directly to the systems users. This
allows the N2 NORS tank ullage left after equalization transfer to the HPGTs to be utilized for day to day nitrogen
demands from the nitrogen bus. The O2 NORS tanks are assumed to be removed after an O2 HPGTs equalization
transfer occurs, and will be either drained to the cabin or used for EVA support ..."